# Coda Toolbar Does Not Show Files in Full Screen

Tags: osx-mavericks, coda

I have a weird issue with Coda's toolbar, when I'm in fullscreen (OS X Mavericks), files will not show.
I'm using OS X version 10.9 and Coda 2.0.8.

Here are some links to screenshots. I need this working, a 13" screen is not so helpful and having the dock and top bar does not help at all. Thanks in advance.

Windowed:
[image: Windowed Screenshot]

Fullscreen:
[image: Fullscreen Screenshot]

Comment: Never found the problem. But instead, it turned out that since I was using a -non retail- version, it had some bugs, I bought the app (a higher version) and it works like a charm again.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Coda 2 to the latest version (2.0.12).
I found the same problem after updating to OS X Mavericks (10.9.1).
I tried updating coda from within the coda application, but it produced an "error extracting the archive". So I downloaded the latest version directly from the website and installed it.

Comment: Yes, I found out about that a while ago.